# AJAX JQuery JSON Post Data not Reaching Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

```
var url =  base_url+"ajax/user/list_user_info/"+userId;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data:{user_id:userId},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {

            if(data.redirect){
                window.location = data.redirect;    
            }
            else {
                $('#profile-main-content').html(data.html);
            }    
        }      
    });
```

Now, this is my request, a pretty standard AJAX request. My problem is that this request is not reaching the controller for some reason. To check I have performed a simple test insert in the database to check the result at first line of the controller's function. But the test does not get inserted. The url is correct because i checked the declaration of the base_url. I know I put the "userId" as an argument and passed it as POST data, but this is me just trying desperately. Any Ideas please? Let me know if i was not clear about anything. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the logs if it throwing any error while posting the request?

Comment: I'm using codeigniter, but i dont have any logs enabled, also the debugger is not working, probably because i'm using a 32bit version on a 64-bit OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
data:{user_id:userId}
```

try:

```
data: JSON.stringify({user_id:userId})
```

The reason for this is that you specified a request content type of `application/json` so you need to send JSON. In your code you are not sending a JSON request - you are sending a simple `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request. And since you have already passed the userId in the POST body you probably don't need to repeat it in your url. Use either one or the other method to send this information to your server.

Also in order to more easily debug javascript errors I strongly suggest you to use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). Among many things it allows you to see the exact requests/responses being sent during an AJAX call and analyze the exact error message you are getting from the server. It makes debugging problems much easier.

Comment: I removed the data part, and decided to pass it in the url as an argument, but still nothing. I also tried the stringify, but got nothing.

Comment: What is the expected result? Have you tried analyzing the response from the server using FireBug? Probably it will contain more information about the error. Also try debugging your server side script. By the way you haven't mentioned anything about your server side part - what language/framework are you using, providing a sample source code, ...

Comment: Hey thanks man, the problem was that, in the controller, i had the same function declared twice, and since i'm working with no debugger, it didnt show.