# dataType: 'json' vs data: JSON.stringify(obj) in $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have this data structure:

```
var formValues = {
        TemporaryToken: a.userStatus.get("TemporaryToken"),
        MemorableWordPositionAndValues:[
            {
                Position: a.userStatus.get("MemorableWordPositions")[0],
                Value: this.$('[name="login-memorable-character-1"]').val()
            },
            {
                Position: a.userStatus.get("MemorableWordPositions")[1],
                Value: this.$('[name="login-memorable-character-2"]').val()
            },
            {
                Position: a.userStatus.get("MemorableWordPositions")[2],
                Value: this.$('[name="login-memorable-character-3"]').val()
            }
        ]
    }
```

And when I send it with $.ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'PUT',
        //dataType:"json",
        data: JSON.stringify(formValues),
        success:function (data) {

        }
    });
```

It sends the request. However, if I send it like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'PUT',
        dataType:"json",
        data: formValues,
        success:function (data) {

        }
    });
```

I receive a 400 Bad Request. Is this a problem on the server or is JSON.stringify doing something different to just setting the dataType to 'json'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is expecting a JSON string, not form parameters. `JSON.stringify` converts your form parameters object/array into a JSON string, which is what your server appears to be expecting.

Comment: How the F do you know it's going to ASP??

Comment: I don't, i made an assumption due to the number of ASP questions that come here with the same problem, Was i completely off? Whether it's ASP or not, the simple fact is the server rejects it with a 400 response code if it isn't JSON according to your question.

Comment: ha, excellent. Well AFAIK it's going to a C# API, but the guys do use ASP as well!

Comment: Updated to a non-server language specific answer, :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is still sending the request in the second attempt; it is simply that your server does not understand the request. That is because jQuery automatically processes the `formValues` data into a query string before sending the data. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> data
>
> Type: Object, String
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the traditional setting (described below).

So, you must use `JSON.stringify()`, or not use JSON. Note that setting `processData` to false won't help, since it will simply send the string `[object Object]` to your server. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438741/ajax-jquery-json-post-data-not-reaching-controller?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

What about `$.param()`?

```
var my_data = {};
my_data.post_name = 'post_value';
$.ajax({
    url:'/post_url.php'
    data:$.param(my_data);
    ...
});
```